# i am getting a runtime error NZEC pls tell me whats the problem

Tags: python, dynamic, runtime-error

I made a program of finding max sum of path of matrix. You can either go down,right or diagonal, starting from 0,0 till its bottom right element.

```
for z in range(int(input())):
   n,m = input().split(" ")
   n = int(n)
   m = int(m)
   arr = []
   ans = []
   for i in range(n):
      s = list(input().split(" "))
      s = list(map(int,s))
      arr.append(s)
      ans.append([0 for y in range(m)])
   for i in range(0,n,1):
      for j in range(0,m,1):
         if i==0 and j==0:
            ans[i][j] = arr[i][j]
         elif i==0 and j!=0:
            ans[i][j] = ans[i][j-1] + arr[i][j]
         elif j==0 and i!=0:
            ans[i][j] = ans[i-1][j] + arr[i][j]
         else:
            ans[i][j] = max(ans[i-1][j],ans[i-1][j-1],ans[i][j-1]) + arr[i][j]        
  print(ans[n-1][m-1])
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation, it's critical for Python code.

Comment: What is `NZEC`? That doesn't sound like a Python error. Please post the full error message, including the traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is in python and therefore it should have a proper indentation or else you will get an error.

The possible reason for getting NZEC error:

1. Infinite Recursion – or if you are run out of stack memory.
2. Make sure your input and output are exactly the same as the test cases. It is advisable to test your program using a computer code that matches your output with the specified outputs exactly.
3. Another common reason for getting this error is when you make basic programming mistakes like dividing by 0.
4. Check for the values of your variables, they can be vulnerable to integer flow.
5. Directly trying to compute factorial above 20, if you are – find another way to do that.
6. NZEC error is a runtime error and occurs mostly when a negative array index is accessed.

For more information, you can check [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nzec-error-in-python)

Check for edge cases, somewhere you might be accessing an array with a negative index.

I hope it helps.